# Combine multiple timestamped lines into a single line

Tags: bash, shell

I have thousands on many lines in a text file. Some consist of 2 lines, some have 1 line, as seen below:

```
1
00:01:18,479 --> 00:01:20,514
Dr. Oppenheimer.

2
00:01:24,052 --> 00:01:25,653
As we begin, I believe you have

3
00:01:25,686 --> 00:01:27,688
a statement to read
into the record.

4
00:01:29,523 --> 00:01:30,725
Yes, Your Honor.

5
00:01:30,758 --> 00:01:32,861
We're
not judges, Doctor.

6
00:01:32,895 --> 00:01:33,929
Of course.

......so on and on...........
```

I want to know how to convert a sentence that only consists of 2 lines into one line so that the final result is like this:

```
1
00:01:18,479 --> 00:01:20,514
Dr. Oppenheimer.

2
00:01:24,052 --> 00:01:25,653
As we begin, I believe you have

3
00:01:25,686 --> 00:01:27,688
a statement to read into the record.

4
00:01:29,523 --> 00:01:30,725
Yes, Your Honor.

5
00:01:30,758 --> 00:01:32,861
We're not judges, Doctor.

6
00:01:32,895 --> 00:01:33,929
Of course.

......so on and on...........
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk -F'\n' -v OFS='\n' -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' 'NF==4{$3=$3" "$4; NF=3}1' file
1
00:01:18,479 --> 00:01:20,514
Dr. Oppenheimer.

2
00:01:24,052 --> 00:01:25,653
As we begin, I believe you have

3
00:01:25,686 --> 00:01:27,688
a statement to read into the record.

4
00:01:29,523 --> 00:01:30,725
Yes, Your Honor.

5
00:01:30,758 --> 00:01:32,861
We're not judges, Doctor.

6
00:01:32,895 --> 00:01:33,929
Of course.
```

Comment: While `NF=3` will do what you want in GNU awk and some others, you should mention that it's undefined behavior so it'll do different things in different awks. If you do `$NF=$NF` afterwards then it'll work in more awks (e.g. it'll then work in freebsd awk) than if you don't do that but it's still undefined behavior and so I expect there are still some awks out there where it won't do what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -00 -lpe '$i = 0; s/\n/(++$i > 2) ? " " : "\n"/ge' input.txt
```

- `-00` turns on the "paragraph mode" which reads the file in blocks separated by more than one newline;
- `-l` removes the final newlines from the input and adds them to output;
- `-p` reads the file block by block, prints the implicit variable after running the code;
- `s/\n/.../g` replaces each newline with the `...` part;
- `s///e` interprets the replacement as code to evaluate;
- `(++$i > 2) ? " " : "\n"` is used to keep the first two newlines, replacing any other by a space. The variable $i serves as a line counter inside each block, it's incremented on each newline, and once it has seen 2 of them, the ternary operator `?:` starts returning a space instead of a newline.

Answer (score 2):

With awk

```
awk '
    BEGIN {
        RS = ""     # seqeunces of empty lines separate records
        FS = "\n"   # newlines separate fields
    }
    {
        print $1
        print $2
        for (i = 3; i <= NF; i++) printf "%s ", $i
        printf "\n\n"
    }
' file
```

Comment: If you make it `for (i = 3; i < NF; i++) printf "%s ", $i; print $i ORS` then it won't add a blank char to the end of the last line of each record.